# How to remove a not working Android emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

In Android Studio, it shows an extra emulator. How can I remove it?

I do a refresh, but it doesn't get deleted. And when I want to run it, this error shows. I uninstalled Android Studio and emulator, but the problem wasn't solved.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFYpg.jpg)